# DataType between different process and architectures - Writing a correct DllImport

Tags: c#, pinvoke, 64-bit, dllimport, type-conversion

I have a main application written in C# that runs as a x64 bit application, it communicates through dll import with a standard native unmanaged C/C++ dll of which I have also the header.

I need help for setting out the correct dataTypes.

So i expose one of the methods I have to call and the data types defined in the dll header.

```
typedef int DLL_IMP_EXP (* INJECTDLL)(HANDLE, DWORD, LPCTSTR, DWORD, HINSTANCE *);
```

**HANDLE** is defined as **void***

**DWORD** is defined as **unsigned long**

**LPCTSTR** is defined as **__nullterminated CONST CHAR***

**HINSTANCE** gives me this line for definition: **DECLARE_HANDLE(HINSTANCE);** ?!?

Using Unicode declaration of the function:
**LPCWSTR** is defined as **__nullterminated CONST WCHAR***

Please help me writing the correct declaration of the:

```
[DllImport ("Inject.dll", VariousParameters)]
public static extern int InjectDll(CorrectDataTypes);
```

Compiling *VariousParameters* if needed, and obviously *CorrectDataTypes*.

Comment: FYI, please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what tags are used for here. Also, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: Asking a question to learn how to do this by yourself is quite okay.  "Write the code for me" is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And [IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx) is used for a pointer or a handle - it will be 32 bits on a 32 bit system and 64 on a 64 bit system.  So if you have anything that is a raw pointer or a  handle use an IntPtr and it will work correctly on both systems.  However your last parameter is a pointer to a handle - use a ref to handle the pointer.  So in this case since it's a pointer to a handle, the parameter will be a ref to an IntPtr.

For standard numeric types, those will map directly to the .NET data types - you can get more details at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446538.aspx).

Null terminated strings are handled correctly, although you'll need to specify whether it uses ANSI or Unicode strings.

Finally P/Invoke assumes a StdCall [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) (which is what the Windows API uses).  If you're not using that, which the function prototype would include STDCALL or __stdcall in it, the standard C calling convention is Cdecl.  Although you'll have to find out what DLL_IMP_EXP expands to.

So your P/Invoke declaration should be:

```
[DllImport ("Inject.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int InjectDll(IntPtr handle, uint dword, string str, uint dword2, ref IntPtr hInstance);
```

Comment: I've found definition of DLL_IMP_EXP.

#ifdef DLL_EXPORT // Not Defined
    #define DLL_IMP_EXP __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_IMP_EXP __declspec(dllimport) // So is this one
#endif

To get Process handle from the x64 environment i use process.Handle property, is it safe to send it like InjectDll(process.Handle,...).
Handle is declared as IntPtr.

Comment: To get Process handle from the x64 environment i use process.Handle property, is it safe to send it like InjectDll(process.Handle,...).

First dword Parameter is obtained through the invocation of the function DWORD DLL_IMP_EXP GetProcessInfo(DWORD dwPID).

So [DllImport ("Inject.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern uint GetProcessInfo(uint dwPID);
is it safe to send it like GetProcessInfo(process.Id); process.Id is defined as int in the x64 env.

Comment: @Relok - that's way too much for a comment, but it looks like what you are doing is OK.  An int and a uint are both 32 bits, so that will generally work.  As long as your datatype in C# is the same size as the one in C/C++ you'll generally be fine.  See this table http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/essentialpinvoke.aspx

Comment: Very useful table. I will make some tests.